# Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large?

Tags: r, plot, fuzzy-logic

I'm trying to plot "System" variables in graph in R Language. this is Linguistic Variable System. I got error message: "Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large" how I can plot "system"?

Here is my code:

```
## Setup the universe, the range of values that we will process.
    sets_options("universe", seq(from = 0, to = 40, by = 0.1))

    ## Setup the Linguistic Variables for BMI, A1C blood pressure & underwriter rating.
    variables <-
      set(
        bmi = 
          fuzzy_partition(varnames =
                            c(under = 9.25,
                              fit = 21.75,
                              over = 27.5,
                              obese  = 35),
                          sd = 3.0),
        a1c =
          fuzzy_partition(varnames =
                            c(l = 4, n = 5.25, h = 7),
                          FUN = fuzzy_cone, radius = 5),
        rating =
          fuzzy_partition(varnames =
                            c(DC = 10, ST = 5, PF = 1),
                          FUN = fuzzy_cone, radius = 5),
        bp = 
          fuzzy_partition(varnames =
                            c(norm = 0,
                              pre = 10,
                              hyp = 20,
                              shyp = 30),
                          sd = 2.5)
      )


    ## set up rules
    rules <-
      set(
        fuzzy_rule(bmi %is% under || bmi %is% obese  || a1c %is% l,
                   rating %is% DC),
        fuzzy_rule(bmi %is% over || a1c %is% n || bp %is% pre,
                   rating %is% ST),
        fuzzy_rule(bmi %is% fit && a1c %is% n && bp %is% norm,
                   rating %is% PF)
      )
    ## combine to a system
    system <- fuzzy_system(variables, rules)
    print(system)

    plot(system) ## plots variables
```

Comment: Where do the functions `sets_options()`, `fuzzy_system()`, etc. come from?

Comment: I get the same error in RStudio when I try to plot something and the plot quadrant is too small - if I increase the dimensions of my plot quadrant the error goes away.

Comment: One option is to use `pdf()`, `png()` or similar functions to create a larger plot canvas and plot directly to a file.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your comments. 
I just added code below, it's working now!

```
    png("p3_sa_para.png", 800, 600)
    par(mfrow=c(1,2))
    plot(system, ylab="Beta",xlab="Iteration")
    dev.off()
```